# User account does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory'

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory

I am trying to build web application with nextjs and nextauth, therefore I created an app registration on my personal MS account. I am using the `AzureADProvider` but I get the following error message on `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<My project GUID>/login` after I entered the credentials of my school email.

`AADSTS50020: User account '<My schools email>' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/<School GUID I guess>/' does not exist in tenant 'Default Directory' and cannot access the application '<My app registration>'(<Project name>) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account`
The goal is to be able to login with my, as well as all other students accounts of our school, so there does not need to be a separate registration and only students can login and the teachers can identify the students by their mail (because most of them would register with crappy mails and usernames :/ ).

Answer (score 4):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

The error usually occurs if the Azure AD Application is registered as Single-Tenant, but other personal account or other tenant users are trying to login.

**To resolve the error, try the below:**

I created an **Azure AD Application** as "*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)*" like below:

[image]

For ***sample***, I used the below **authorize endpoint** to authenticate users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

**The user signed-in successfully like below:**

[image]

Also make sure to use **`common`** endpoint to authorize the users.

- If you only want only Azure Active Directory users only to login the register the Application as "*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant)*" and make use of **`organizations`** endpoint.

***If still the issue persists***, refer the below MsDoc:

[Error AADSTS50020 - User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant - Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist)

Comment: I already have Multitenant selected. When I added the user manually, I was able to get further, but the next step was to get permission from the admin (for what I will stay in contact with my schools management). But still, I would not want to add all users manually. Can I whitelist a whole organization? Another idea was to create the app registration from the school organization, if they let me.